# Lumia 820 compass going crazy

Tags: lumia, here

Whenever I use the HERE Drive+ Beta app on my Lumia 820 the compass spins to face random directions at 1 second intervals. It does this even if the phone is sitting on the kitchen table not moving. Any ideas what's going on? Anyone seen this issue before?

It's also worth noting I have a compass app which does NOT suffer the same issue!

Comment: Which app EXACTLY are you using? I am asking because the Nokia apps for this that were branded Nokia Drive have since been upgraded to Here Drive. Check to see what you have installed as it would be useful for whoever can answer this to know which app they need to look into.

Comment: thanks, I edited the original post to state I'm using the HERE Drive+ Beta app

Comment: Does it suffer this problem when moving, in view of the sky? could it be the case that they're (only) using GPS to derive heading?

Comment: I don't think you can derive heading from GPS, doesn't it need the compass for that?

Comment: It's relatively trivial to derive a heading form two different GPS positions (in the same way you can derive speed). It may be that they've chosen to do that, rather than power up the compass to query.

Comment: that seems to make the most sense actually.

Answer (score 1):

The app *might* be deriving heading from sequential GPS readings, and without a clear view of the sky, or without moving at all, the general "fuzz" and noise in GPS signals may make it think it's going crazy.